# How to integrate large trigonometric equations with python?

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-integration

In my program I have to recreate the [galerkin-method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galerkin_method), with which I have to do some integrations which I now do with `sympy.integrate`.

My problem is, that in cases where the equation contains multiple trigonometric functions or also an added e function (it should be able to solve everything), sympy calculates for ever. I'm also working with `sympy.symbols` because with those integrations I'm creating a system of equations which has to be solved. I need a antiderivative and not just a solution for one value.

Is there a numeric integration method or something else which gives back an accurate value?
I tried with `sympy.Integral(equation).evalf(1)` and there the error is way too high or the returned decimal numbers are too long which brings me back to a way too high runtime.

The Functions can look like this:

`(-4*x**3*sin(2*x) + 2*cos(x)*cos(2*x))*(cos(x) + 1)`

and I have to integrate like 20 of these.

Comment: To me it's a bit unclear what type of "solution function" you're actually looking for. Do you need a symbolic integration? Then what would numeric integration help?  Do  you want to use the galerkin-method to ultimately solve a system numerically?

Comment: Plus- are you sure a symbolic integral exists?

Comment: I didn't knew the word I was looking for, its a antiderivative, I added it in my edit.
Yes guess they do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SymPy's integrate function tries a number of different integration methods one of which is the Risch algorithm which can be very slow in some cases. There is also the "manual" integration method which is not as complete as Risch but suffers less from occasional extreme slowness. There is some description of this here:
https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/integrals/integrals.html#internals

The problem in the example that you have given is that it gets stuck in heurisch. So let's try "manual" instead:

```
In [1]: expr = (-4*x**3*sin(2*x) + 2*cos(x)*cos(2*x))*(cos(x) + 1)                                                                

In [2]: expr                                                                                                                      
Out[2]: 
⎛     3                             ⎞             
⎝- 4⋅x ⋅sin(2⋅x) + 2⋅cos(x)⋅cos(2⋅x)⎠⋅(cos(x) + 1)

In [3]: %time anti1 = expr.integrate(x, manual=True)                                                                              
CPU times: user 39.7 s, sys: 232 ms, total: 39.9 s
Wall time: 43.1 s

In [4]: anti1                                                                                                                     
Out[4]: 
   3    3                                                              3                                           ⌠            
8⋅x ⋅cos (x)      3               2                           x   4⋅sin (x)                           sin(4⋅x)     ⎮  2    3    
──────────── + 2⋅x ⋅cos(2⋅x) - 3⋅x ⋅sin(2⋅x) - 3⋅x⋅cos(2⋅x) + ─ - ───────── + 2⋅sin(x) + 2⋅sin(2⋅x) + ──────── - 8⋅⎮ x ⋅cos (x) dx
     3                                                        2       3                                  8         ⌡
```

So that took 40 seconds but the result is not completely integrated: `manualintegrate` has left an unevaluated integral in there. We can finish that off using normal `integrate` by calling `doit`:

```
In [5]: %time anti1.doit()                                                                                                        
CPU times: user 4.46 s, sys: 142 ms, total: 4.61 s
Wall time: 4.81 s
Out[5]: 
   3    3                          2    3                                                    2                      3           
8⋅x ⋅cos (x)      3            16⋅x ⋅sin (x)      2           2         2            32⋅x⋅sin (x)⋅cos(x)   112⋅x⋅cos (x)        
──────────── + 2⋅x ⋅cos(2⋅x) - ───────────── - 8⋅x ⋅sin(x)⋅cos (x) - 3⋅x ⋅sin(2⋅x) - ─────────────────── - ───────────── - 3⋅x⋅c
     3                               3                                                        3                  9              

                     3                    2                                      
          x   284⋅sin (x)   112⋅sin(x)⋅cos (x)                           sin(4⋅x)
os(2⋅x) + ─ + ─────────── + ────────────────── + 2⋅sin(x) + 2⋅sin(2⋅x) + ────────
          2        27               9                                       8
```

So it took another few seconds to get that result. This is now a complete antiderivative as we can verify:

```
In [6]: simplify(expr - _.diff(x))                                                                                                
Out[6]: 0
```

That means we can do this particular integral in around 50 seconds with `expr.integrate(x, manual=True).doit()`.

Actually this particular example can be done in more like 5 seconds if it is rewritten from sin/cos to exp:

```
In [1]: expr = (-4*x**3*sin(2*x) + 2*cos(x)*cos(2*x))*(cos(x) + 1)                                                                

In [2]: %time expr.rewrite(exp).expand().integrate(x).expand().rewrite(sin).simplify()                                            
CPU times: user 5.3 s, sys: 21.2 ms, total: 5.32 s
Wall time: 5.33 s
Out[2]: 
                                 3                                             2                                                
   3             3            2⋅x ⋅cos(3⋅x)      2             2            2⋅x ⋅sin(3⋅x)                                4⋅x⋅cos
2⋅x ⋅cos(x) + 2⋅x ⋅cos(2⋅x) + ───────────── - 6⋅x ⋅sin(x) - 3⋅x ⋅sin(2⋅x) - ───────────── - 12⋅x⋅cos(x) - 3⋅x⋅cos(2⋅x) - ───────
                                    3                                             3                                           9 


(3⋅x)   x                            13⋅sin(3⋅x)   sin(4⋅x)
───── + ─ + 13⋅sin(x) + 2⋅sin(2⋅x) + ─────────── + ────────
        2                                 27          8    

In [3]: simplify(expr - _.diff(x))                                                                                                
Out[3]: 0
```

Although this answer looks different to the previous one there are an infinite number of ways of rewriting trig expressions using trig identities but they should be equivalent up to an additive constant (as required for antiderivatives).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need the integration to be symbolic, and you know the integration bounds, then you could integrate numerically. A pragmatic starting point would be the trapezoidal rule. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule. The accuracy could be arbitrarily increased by finer steps (within bounds).

Increasing the accuracy by using a higher order is a bit more elaborate programmatically, but numerically more efficient. An implementation usually starts only to make sense when computation times are higher than the programming time)

```
import math
import matplotlib

sin=math.sin  
cos=math.cos

def f(x):
    return (-4*x**3*sin(2*x) + 2*cos(x)*cos(2*x))*(cos(x) + 1)

x0 = 0              # lower bound
x1 = 2.8            # upper bound (not exactly resolved in this example)
dx = 0.01           # integration step size

F_int = 0
x=x0

while x < x1:
    f_n = f(x)
    f_n_plusdx = f(x+dx)
    dF = 0.5*(f_n+f_n_plusdx)*dx     # calc the trapezoid area
    F_int += dF                      # sum of the integration
    x+=dx                            # next dx.

print(F_int)
```